# While using nunique with groupby in pandas how to avoid counting row with blank/nan

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

While using nunique in groupby how to avoid counting row with blank/nan, Also I cannot drop the rows as I have some other useful information in the same row other columns.

current df:

```
nc1|n1
A1 | A
A2 | A
nan |     nan
B2   |     B
B3    |    B
B4     |   B
```

```py
df['c1'] = df['nc1']
df.groupby(['n1'], as_index=False).aggregate({'c1':'nunique'})
```

output:

```
nc1     |  n1   |    c1
A1      |  A     |    2
A2      |  A    |     2
nan     | nan    |    1
B2       | B     |    2
B3       | B    |     2
B2      |  B   |      2
```

expected:

```
nc1     |  n1  |     c1
A1     |   A   |      2
A2      |  A    |     2
nan     | nan  |
B2      |  B  |       2
B3      |  B  |       2
B2     |   b  |       2
```

Comment: What do you mean by `nan | nan |` in expected ?

Comment: Please explain more thoroughly.

Comment: Why don't you just drop rows with all nan before doing the group by.

Comment: I didn't want to drop rows as only these columns are empty, I have other columns with useful data, so dropping the entire row would lead to dropping of meaningful data.

Comment: I removed it successfully without deleting the entire row by writing this simple line df['c1'][df.n1 == ""] = ""